# round number instead of decimals

Tags: javascript, math

I just need to remove the decimals from the data variable using the following function. Can't seem to manage it at the moment.

```
maths.multiplyInteger = function(sequence) {
        if (sequence.length == 0) {
            return 0;
        }

        var result = maths.getInteger(sequence[0]);

        function loop(data) {
            for (var i = 1, length = sequence.length; i < length; i++) {
                var result = result * maths.getInteger(sequence[i]);
            }
        }

        loop(sequence);

        return {
            input: sequence,
            output: result
        }
    };
```

Data variable looks as follows:

```
 var data = {
        first: [3.57, 2.43, '043'],
        second: [7.26, 1.43, '025'],
        third: ['076', 3.0, 6.42],
    };
```

Comment: Are you looking for `Math.floor()`?  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/floor

Comment: please add the wanted result as well.

Comment: so wanted result for first would be 3*2*43. Tried Math.floor() but couldn't get it working.

Comment: Please be more specific.  Are you getting errors? Are you getting unexpected results?

Comment: Unexpected results so 3.57*2.43*43 needs to actually be 258 but is coming out as 3.

Answer (score 4):

`Math.floor()` works fine but firstly you have to refer to the elements properly. Suggested approach: `Object.keys()` and `Array#map`.

```js
var data = {
  first: [3.57, 2.43, '043'],
  second: [7.26, 1.43, '025'],
  third: ['076', 3.0, 6.42],
},
res = {};

Object.keys(data).forEach(function(v){
  res[v] = data[v].map(c => Math.floor(c)).reduce((a,b) => a * b);
})

console.log(res);

//Object.keys() function returns array of all keys of the data object, it will look
//like: ['first', 'second', 'third']
//Then, use map function to iterate over it to catch every key value,
//which is an array (for example - [3.57, 2.43, '043']
//Then, catch every element in this array with map function and round it down
//using Math.floor() function (to the nearest integer under)
```

Comment: I can see this returns the correct results, but don't totally understand how.

Comment: @user3770540 I've added description, I hope it will you understand my code.

Comment: It make sense but how would i then parse that into multiplication function?

Comment: @user3770540 You want to multiply every element inside each array? For example - `3*2*43` and return the value?

Comment: Yes exactly. Thats what is want, the function i'm using at present is at the top of the page

Comment: Thanks you, perfect.

Answer (score 1):

You could map the result of [`Math.floor`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/floor).

```js
var data = { first: [3.57, 2.43, '043'], second: [7.26, 1.43, '025'], third: ['076', 3.0, 6.42] },
    result = Object.keys(data).map(function (k) { return data[k].map(Math.floor); });

console.log(result);
```